# rsync -p. why would you want to preserve owner, permissions

Tags: linux, backup, mac-osx, rsync, terminal

basically the title.
I'm lacking unix basics but on windows if I backup with robocopy I wouldn't want to preserve ownership bc then I would have to take ownership of it again anyway when replaying the backup. (default is actually data, attr, timestamps)

I'm trying to backup a macbook in order to reset it and I'm hesitant to use the global archive flag -a.
Will I have to take ownership of the files or can I just use rsync -a with no problems later on?

Comment: Have you considered using TimeMachine?  I think it is built in.

Comment: `Will I have to take ownership of the files` - Maybe, difficult to know the specific details matter, and you really haven't given us any. For any serious backup system, you really should test and see what happens. Test, test, test.  A backup without a tested restore procedure is close to worthless.

Comment: @Slartibartfast funny you should say that @ link. I dont trust stuff like that. I can use it and I did make one, but I prefer to have the raw files too. you know, just in case. also: https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2020/06/03/reinstalling-macos-what-to-try-when-all-else-fails/ and that's the only guide that worked for me and many others it seems. 
// 

"Time Machine is Apple’s magical backup solution. Time Machine saves snapshots of your entire disk. It’s supposed to help restore files that were deleted or changed in an unwanted way, or help you restore a full macOS install. [...]"

Comment: @Zoredache . yea make sense but I asked bc I was genuinely curious. I never had to deploy stuff for companies. All I see is: system; user. So I fail to see the benefit of storing the owner. I guess this is needed if deployment is highly automated? else from my POV it'd be easier to decide ownerless who gets what. I mean it's not encrypted or tied to any key, so I don't see the point.

Answer (score 1):

When you restore your data, do you really want to have to fix your permissions?

Do you have the permissions documented somewhere else so you know what they should be?

> if I backup with robocopy I wouldn't want to preserve ownership

Maybe you don't but 9 times out of 10, I do. Permissions and metadata about files in some cases is as important as the data in the file.

Do you want to share PII with the wrong person? Do you want to give store the salary and personnel database in a place where anyone and everyone can get into it?

These tools are at least partially designed for usage on servers in multi-user systems.

Comment: "These tools are at least partially designed for usage on servers in multi-user systems."
yea I guess that sums it up. it's a domain vs local thing. // 

Even when I think a system's user config files, it will have to get assimilated anyway no? even if I just dump it back into its place.. or not?  // 

to me it just seemed owned files would cause more trouble if for example you name your account differently.   //  

"Do you want to share PII with the wrong person?"  
idk, I have encrypted containers for highly sensitive stuff. so permissions dont really matter there.